# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

do i have my date formated wrong?

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 
'%M-%y').', '.date('h:i:s a').', '3', '1', 'Title', 'Pr', 'BPM001')' at line 1
```

```
INSERT into names(com_id,rec_date,rec_time,rec_type,rec_request,rec_by,batch_id)
values('300','.date('%d-%M-%y').','.date('h:i:s a').','3', '1', 'Title', 'Pr', 'BPM001')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

$q= "INSERT into names(com_id,rec_date,rec_time,rec_type,rec_request,rec_by,batch_id) values('300', '".date("%d-%M-%y")."', '".date("h:i:s a")."', '3', '1', 'Title', 'Pr', 'BPM001')";

Comment: The [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function in MySQL does not work like date from PHP. And you're not even being consistent with the formats, one is for MySQL and the other is for PHP. @acctman You chose an answer that is completely wrong. The only thing it does is not give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mixing php date formatting with mysql formatting. The valid way would be this one:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO names
    (com_id,rec_date,rec_time,rec_type,rec_request,rec_by,batch_id) 
    values('300', DATE_FORMAT('%d-%M-%y'), '".date('h:i:s a')."', '3', '1', 'Title', 'Pr', 'BPM001')
";
```

The recommended way would be to stick to just one of them.

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO names
    (com_id,rec_date,rec_time,rec_type,rec_request,rec_by,batch_id) 
    values('300', DATE_FORMAT('%d-%M-%y'), DATE_FORMAT('%r'), '3', '1', 'Title', 'Pr', 'BPM001')
";
```

**OR**

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO names
    (com_id,rec_date,rec_time,rec_type,rec_request,rec_by,batch_id) 
    values('300', '".date('d-F-Y')."', '".date('h:i:s a')."', '3', '1', 'Title', 'Pr', 'BPM001')
";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$q= "INSERT into names(com_id,rec_date,rec_time,rec_type,rec_request,rec_by,batch_id) values('300', '".date('%d-%M-%y')."', '".date('h:i:s a')."', '3', '1', 'Title', 'Pr', 'BPM001')";
```

Comment: PHP's date does not use `%<something>` formatting.